# How to create custom asp.net validator that works with UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, validation

I think that subject summs it pretty well...

I have created my custom validators that work great when I put them on page in design mode. However if I place them in a usercontrol, and then try to add this user control to the parent page via updatepanel, then my custom validators just won't trigger. They simply don't work.

Does anyone have any clue on what I have to do here?

.net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Custom validators trigger on postback.

My guess is that with the update panel, you're not posting back, hence the validator not firing.

Comment: I have client side validation implemented. So when statically added to the page my custom validators do client side validation without any problem... Basically, that is what I want to achieve here.